# how to find deployed environment?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am using spring/hibernate application and build tool is MAVEN. i configured profiles in pom.xml. is it possible to know the deployed environment? if the packaged war is deployed in UAT/DEV/Production environments, i need to know the environment in which war is running. Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: You may also be able to use server info if they're different machines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set an environment variable on the server that your app can access (e.g. -Denvironment=PROD) or put a file on the server that you can read.

Comment: Hi Duffymo, Thanks for your reply. do i neet to set the environment variable in a machine where the appln is deployed? how can i set the environment variable? and how can i access the same environment variable in my jsp/html page?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it has to be on the server you deploy to.  You'll have to collaborate with the owner of the server.  You can get at it with System.getProperties(), just like all the other system properties.  Your JSPs should not need to know what environment they're in; let the server side tell them what to display.

Comment: Hi Duffymo Thanks for your reply. i need to display the environment in jsp. if it is not possible to access the environment variable in jsp, i should access it at server side right? if so, by calling system.getproperties() returns all. how can i distinguish them? is there any standard to be followed to set up the environment variable?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1016403 what he meant to say is that you should send the information about the evnironmnet from the back-end to your JSP.

Comment: I'm saying that the server side should figure out what the information needs to be displayed and pass it to the JSP.  There shouldn't be any logic in the JSP - it's just for display.

Comment: Hi Duffymo, Thanks for your reply. there should not be any business logic in a jsp. i understood. but still if i want to use it, will there be any issues..i mean can i use System.getproperties() in jsp? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you need to know this option.

In application with database usage better put such options in database, and not to system properies, for avoid situations, when SystemProperties=DEV and Database=UAT.